# gulp 4.0.2 not able to Compile

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I just upgraded to Angular 4.4.7 and typescript 2.7.2. I am trying to run gulp 4.0.2 and compile my ts files but I am getting this error.

> [12:50:49] Did you forget to signal async completion?
> node:events:498
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^

```
**
 * Compile TypeScript sources
 */
gulp.task("compile", gulp.series("clean", function () {
    return gulp.src("./App/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(inlineNg2Template({
            base: "/",                  // Angular2 application base folder
            target: "es6",              // Can swap to es5
            indent: 2,                  // Indentation (spaces)
            useRelativePaths: false,     // Use components relative assset paths
            removeLineBreaks: false,     // Content will be included as one line
            templateExtension: ".html", // Update according to your file extension
            templateFunction: false    // If using a function instead of a string for `templateUrl`, pass a reference to that function here
        }))
        .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
        .pipe(ignore("References.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/App"))
        .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); });
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `on` is problematic, because `on` returns a new stream that does not end when the underlying stream ends.

```js
.on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); });
```

If you remove the line above, things will work again.

If you really need to handle the `error` event, you can do it, but you should still return the piped stream from the task function.

```js
gulp.task("compile", gulp.series("clean", function () {
    const stream = gulp.src("./App/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(inlineNg2Template({
            base: "/",                  // Angular2 application base folder
            target: "es6",              // Can swap to es5
            indent: 2,                  // Indentation (spaces)
            useRelativePaths: false,     // Use components relative assset paths
            removeLineBreaks: false,     // Content will be included as one line
            templateExtension: ".html", // Update according to your file extension
            templateFunction: false    // If using a function instead of a string for `templateUrl`, pass a reference to that function here
        }))
        .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
        .pipe(ignore("References.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/App"));
    stream.on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); });
    return stream;
}));
```

Note though that gulp already prints messages from `error` events, I would not repeat that process manually.

Comment: I still get the same error with this new code [08:01:18] The following tasks did not complete: